# Does curly brackets matter for empty constructor?

Tags: c++

I'm wondering if the following constructors are the same for C++:

```
class foo
{ 
public:
   foo(void){};
...
}
```

and

```
class foo
{
public:
   foo(void);
...
}
```

Do curly brackets matter for these two cases? Thanks much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They're not same. `{}` represents a regular function-body and makes the former [function definition](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Function_definition).

```
foo(void){}; // function definition
foo(void);   // function declaration
```

Comment: Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 6):

Yes they do. The second one will generate `undefined reference to foo::foo` (unless defined in another place). If you can use C++11 or above, you can use

```
foo()=default;
```

to define a compiler generated constructor

Comment: Thanks for the `=default` suggestion!

Comment: Note that `foo()=default;` is not exactly the same as `foo(){}`. The first is a "trivial" constructor, the second is not. User defined constructors are never trivial even if they are empty.

Answer (score 3):

Those brackets declare an empty, inline constructor. In that case, with them, the constructor does exist, it merely does nothing more than the constructor would not already implicitly do.

In the second case, without them, the compiler will expect an implementation elsewhere - such as a .cpp file.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Without it is just a declarations. With both it is a declaration and definition. Try using it - you will get a linker error without the definition